# PyQt4: Sorting a QTableWidget by a column containing an icon

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a database with a list of items, and each item has an associated "rating" field, which is a float ranging from 0-5. Now, when I'm populating the QTableWidget with these items, I want to display an image for the rating instead of the float. So I do this:

```
iconPath = "images/icons/ratings/"+backend.utilities.pickRatingIcon(col)
icon = QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(iconPath))
item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(icon, "")
self.deckTable.setItem(i, j, item)
```

Everything works, but I naturally lose my ability to sort by that column. I can change the third line to this:

```
item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(icon, col)
```

which allows me to sort again, but then I get the float next to the icon which kind of defeats the purpose. Is there a way to display just the icon but sort by the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer that works for me. It's basically the same thing I was doing before - that is, the value is included with the icon. But I'm resizing the column to cover the value, and then preventing it from being resized.

```
item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
# We set our icon and value
item.setIcon(icon)
item.setData(QtCore.Qt.EditRole, QtCore.QVariant(col))
# We set the size of our item. My icon is 80x32 pixels, but it was getting clipped off so I added 5 pixels of width
item.setData(QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole, QtCore.QSize(85,32))
# We prevent the column from being resized. In my case it's the first column, so the index is 0
self.deckTable.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(0, QtGui.QHeaderView.Fixed)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer, it helped me to save some time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must store ratings.

```
item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(icon, "")
self.deckTable.itemsRating[item]=rating
self.deckTable.setItem(i, j, item)
```

And then override sortItems for subclassed QtableWidget and manually rearrange items:

```
class DeckTableWidget(QtGui.QTableWidget):
itemsRating=dict()
def sortItems(self, column, order=QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder):
  _list=[]
  for row in self.rowCount():
      item = self.takeItem(row, column)
      _list.append((item, self.itemsRating[item]))
  _list.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(x.[1], y.[1])
  if order != QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder:
      _list.reverse()
  for row in self.rowCount():
      self.setItem(row, column, _list.pop()[0])
```

Comment: That seems like the proper way to do it, but I found a more elegant solution for my specific problem in the meantime. I'll post my own answer and probably accept it unless someone else comes along with an even better one, and I'm up-voting yours.